# How to use case statement in linq where clause

Tags: c#, linq

Table : Id, Name,Subject,Score

```
1 Pinky English 60

2 Pinky Maths 40

3 Mahesh Maths 50

4 Rani  Maths 50

5 Rani  Eco 50
```

I want to fetch record from table ,when Subject is maths, need record whose score should be more than 50,for remaining subject no condition.

Output :

```
1 Pinky English 60

3 Mahesh Maths 50

4 Rani  Maths 50

5 Rani  Eco 50
```

Query :

```
(from tbl in dbContext.Table1
where tbl.Subject ='Maths'
select tbl)
```

How to add that condition in where clause here.

```
(from tbl in dbContext.Table1 where tbl.Subject ='Maths' select tbl)
```

Comment: what does this have to do with c#? Without any code that shows your current attempts it's pretty hard to help you, as we have no clue what you've tried already and where specifically you're stuck.

Comment: I have already shown attempt

Comment: What isn't working? Apart from the obvious `=` which should be `==`

Comment: Since its closed I can't add this as an answer. 
`var r = dbContext.Table1.Where(x => x.Subject == "Maths" && x.Score >= 50 || x.Subject != "Maths");`

Comment: @Magnus,thanks for ur help.It helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is open I’ll add my comment as an answer.

```
var r = dbContext.Table1
          .Where(x => x.Subject == "Maths" && x.Score >= 50 || x.Subject != "Maths");
```